# Random Numbers from 0 to &HFFFFFFFF

Tags: random, vb6

Are there any ways so I can generate random numbers from 0 to &HFFFFFFFF in Visual Basic 6.0?

I am using the following function

```
Function RandomNumberLong(Lowerbound As Long, Upperbound As Long) As Long
    RandomNumberLong = Clng((Upperbound - Lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + Lowerbound)
End Function
```

If I use

```
x = RandomNumberLong(0,&HFFFFFFFF)
```

It always returns 0

The problem here is the max value of long can hold is 7FFFFFFF or 2147483647 in decimal
So how I am supposed to fix this? Even if I use a single data type it always return negative without unsigned numbers.

According to MSDN Long type

> Long (long integer) variables are stored as signed 32-bit (4-byte)
>   numbers ranging in value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
>   Thetype-declaration character for Long is the ampersand (&).

But the value of FFFFFFFF is equal to -1 or 4294967294 which overflow.

I think I am confused on this.

Edited:

Since this seems to be a little bit complicated, i have coded a small Shell code to use the RDTSC instruction instead to generate a random long number including singed and unsigned.

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _ 
(Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" _ 
(ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Option Explicit

 Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim x(1 To 10) As Byte, VAL As Long

    CopyMemory x(1), &H60, 1 'PUSHAD
    CopyMemory x(2), &H310F, 2 'RDTSC EAX holds a random value

    CopyMemory x(4), &HA3, 1 'MOV EAX
    CopyMemory x(5), VarPtr(VAL), 4 'Pointer of variable // MOV DWORD [VAL],EAX 

    CopyMemory x(9), &H61, 1 'POPAD
    CopyMemory x(10), &HC3, 1 'RET
    CallWindowProc VarPtr(x(1)), 0, 0, 0, 0 'Call the shellcode

    MsgBox VAL
    End Sub
```

Comment: Just use a proper PRNG and read 4 bytes.

Comment: Notice that this method of calling machine code is **not safe**! It will fail on modern Windows systems with [data execution protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention), making it frail or outright crash on modern systems. You *must* mark such memory as executable beforehand using the `VirtualProtect` WinAPI function. [Here’s an example code](http://www.activevb.de/tipps/vb6tipps/tipp0715.html) – albeit with German comments.

Comment: Yep, almost forgot about that, thank you for the head up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&HFFFFFFFF` - represents a 32-bit signed integer, and the value of `&HFFFFFFFF` overflows the integer and becomes `-1`
Hence, when you call `RandomNumberLong` function, you are passing 0 to Lowerbound and -1 to Upperbound

In order to fix this in Vb.NET, use `&HFFFFFFFFL` or `&HFFFFFFFF&` to indicate Long type literal. I am not sure how to fix this as quickly in VB6 as in VB.NET from the example above. I guess you will need to write your own function to convert large HEX numbers to double and pass the number instead of the HEX.

EDIT:
I don't think VB6 allows you to convert `&HFFFFFFFF` to anything but base 16, which overflows and results in -1:

EDIT 2:
You can convert some Hex numbers into other datatype by adding `&` to the end:

```
&HFFFF = -1
&HFFFF& = 65535
```

Still, there seems to be a limit to the Hex number in VB6 (base 16 only?) because:

```
VB.NET:
&HFFFFFFFF&=4294967295

VB6:
&HFFFFFFFF&=-1
```

[MSDN: Type Characters (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/s9cz43ek.aspx)

> The compiler normally construes an integer literal to be in the decimal (base 10) number system. You can force an integer literal to be hexadecimal (base 16) with the &H prefix, and you can force it to be octal (base 8) with the &O prefix. The digits that follow the prefix must be appropriate for the number system.

Comment: Thank you George for clearing this up. I have used the RDTSC instruction instead to generate a random long number. You can see it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Truth is that VB6 `Long` is 32-bit *signed* integer data type. As such it simply cannot store `&HFFFFFFFF` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). But (1) you seem to be OK with using `Long` anyway, and (2) you do not explain what is your use case, and if it is  really that crucial to work in a positive range only.

One can use the following function to generate random `Long` values from the whole range of `Long` data type (i.e. from `-&H80000000` to `&H7FFFFFFF`):

```
Function RandomNumberLong() As Long
    RandomNumberLong = &H7FFFFFFF * Rnd() + (-1 - &H7FFFFFFF) * Rnd()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that VB6 converts any hex number which exits out of only "F" to -1

This will make your function to use -1 as its upperbound, and causes it to return 0

By separating the 8 digits into 2 variables with 4 digits, you still have the same problem as VB6 will still convert &HFFFF to -1 which will make your function to return 0 again.

A solution is to add &H10000 to the 4 digit variables before converting, and substracting Val("&H10000") after the conversion has been done.

After that you can use these 2 values to obtain 2 random numbers, and combine them into 1 random 8 digit hex number.

Below is a test project which shows what i mean:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim strX As String
  Dim lngX As Long
  strX = RndHex("FFFFFFFF")
  lngX = Val("&H" & strX)
  Caption = strX & " = " & CStr(Hex$(lngX)) & " = " & CStr(lngX)
End Sub

Function RndHex(strMax As String) As String
  Dim strMax1 As String, strMax2 As String
  Dim lngMax1 As Long, lngMax2 As Long
  Dim lngVal1 As Long, lngVal2 As Long
  Dim strVal1 As String, strVal2 As String
  'make sure max is 8 digits
  strMax1 = Right$("00000000" & strMax, 8)
  'split max in 2 parts
  strMax2 = Right$(strMax1, 4)
  strMax1 = Left$(strMax1, 4)
  'convert max values from string to values
  lngMax1 = Val("&H1" & strMax1) - Val("&H10000")
  lngMax2 = Val("&H1" & strMax2) - Val("&H10000")
  'calculate separate random values
  lngVal1 = CLng(lngMax1 + 1) * Rnd
  lngVal2 = CLng(lngMax2 + 1) * Rnd
  'convert values to 4 digit hex strings
  strVal1 = Right$("0000" & Hex$(lngVal1), 4)
  strVal2 = Right$("0000" & Hex$(lngVal2), 4)
  'combine 2 random values and return the result as an 8 digit hex string
  RndHex = strVal1 & strVal2
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'seed random generator with system timer
  Randomize
End Sub
```

Run the project above and click the command button and view the values in the caption of the form.

Comment: "The problem is that VB6 converts any hex number which exits out of only "F" to -1" - not entirely accurate. `&HF=15`, `&HFF=255`, `&HFFF=4095`, `&HFFFF=-1`, `&HFFFFF=1048575`, `&HFFFFFF=16777215`, `&HFFFFFFF=268435455`, `&HFFFFFFFF=-1`and everything beyond that results in a compile error.

Comment: Furthermore, `&HFFFF&=65535`. So only after large HEX numbers such as `&HFFFFFFFF` do we start seeing an overflow. Everything before that looks good.

Comment: I agree, I simplified the answer a bit. I guess I should have said sets of 4 bytes. I didn't think of adding a & to the end, because it won't work with 8 bytes, nice addition!

Answer (score 0):

`Rnd` will only give you 24 bits of randomness since it returns a `Single`.

```
 RandomNumberLong = Clng(&HFFFF * Rnd()) + (Clng(&HFFFF * Rnd()) * &H10000)
```

will construct a 32-bit value from two 16-bit random integers.

UPDATE - well, it won't, because as Hrqls points out, `&HFFFF` is `-1` in VB. Instead:

```
 RandomNumberLong = Clng(65535 * Rnd()) + (Clng(65535 * Rnd()) * 65536)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.  Right now, he's getting 0 bits of randomness.  :P  That error almost certainly has nothing to do with the precision of a `Single`.  (With that said, though, this is still good info for later, when the thing's actually able to produce numbers.)

Comment: I tested your function and it returns one of the following FFFEFFFF or
FFFF0000 or FFFFFFFF
or 0.

Comment: `Single` is 32-bit in VB6.

Comment: Yes, Single is 32 bits, but Rnd returns a value between 0 and 1, so the sign bit and 7 exponent bits don't add any randomness.

Comment: +1 for splitting the 8 digits into 2x 4 digits ... the problem still exits though as vb still converts &HFFFF to -1 ... see my answer below which works around that issue

Comment: @Hrqls use `&HFFFF&` to convert it to `65535` and not to `-1`